# Get values from custom array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have got the below array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Contact Number
            [1] => 35443545
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Address
            [1] => vvvv
        )

)
```

I would like to display as

```
Contact Number
35443545
<hr>
Address
vvvv
```

My code

```
foreach($address_box_content as $k=>$address)
{
    echo '<h2>'.$address[$k].'</h2><p>'.$address[$k+1].'</p>';
}
```

But for some reason it is printing the first 2 lines and then displaying a notice 'Undefined offset:2'

Comment: `echo '<h2>'.$address[0].'</h2><p>'.$address[1].'</p><hr>';`

Comment: You need Array Flattern function.

Comment: Should rename your vars, name `$address` to `$property` and it will be more clear

Comment: @t3chguy Superb....so stupid I am. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is an array.  One whose elements are (also) arrays.  Each array that you have stored has 2 elements, 0 and 1.

When you loop, `$k` is the index of the *main* (*outer*) array.  Its value doesn't make any sense in the inner array.  You just need to loop over the outer array, and print the `0` and `1` elements from the inner one.

```
foreach($address_box_content as $address)
{
    echo '<h2>'.$address[0].'</h2><p>'.$address[1].'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you're getting undefined offset error because you're using $k which is the index of the outer array

You can do something like:

```
foreach($address_box_content as $addresses){
    foreach($addresses as $address){
        echo '<h2>', $address, '</h2><p>', $address, '</p>';
    }
}
```

And if you want to get the index of inner array:

```
foreach($address_box_content as $addresses){
    foreach($addresses as $key => $address){
        echo '<h2>', $address[$key], '</h2><p>', $address[$key], '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This is your array 
$data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Contact Number
            [1] => 35443545
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Address
            [1] => vvvv
        )

)
simple way to print array 
for($i=0;$<count($data);$i++)
{
  echo  "<h2>".$data[$i][$0]."</h2>"."<p>".$value[$i][1]."</p>"."<hr />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, for each element you define a key and a value which are $k and $address.

$k will be 0 and 1, $address will be 0 and 1, and then 0 and 1.

the undefined offset error is because you call $k plus 1 that on the second foeach iteration try to access to position 1+1 (2) doesn't find anything.

you could use something like:

```
foreach($address_box_content as $data => $value) {

    echo    "<h2>" . $value[0] . "</h2>"
          . "<p>" . $value[1] . "</p>"
          . "<hr />";

}
```